# How to extract sub strings in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a lot of dates like
March 26 2013
April 12 2012 so on.
I want to extract the month,day and year from these strings separately.
Like March , 26 , 2013.
How will I do it with regular expressions in python?

Comment: `month, day, year = "March 26 2013".split()`

Answer (score 4):

```
dates = ["March 26 2013", "April 12 2012"]
for date in dates:
    date, month, year = date.split()
    print date, month, year
```

**Output**

```
March 26 2013
April 12 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about python, but the regex could be something like this:

```
(?<month>\w{3,9})\s+(?<day>0?[1-9]|[1,2][0-9]|3[0,1])\s+(?<year>[1-9][0-9]{3})
```

I used *named capture groups* for easily accessing the seperate strings.
[Here](http://www.rubular.com/r/vfpGZLRwhk) you can see it in action.